# Is there a R function to check and remove empty strings in a dataframe?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Recently I want to deal with some TCGA data and draw some KM survival plot.
But accidently I found something strange:

```
>dat3
                TUMOR_STAGE OS_MONTHS  OS_STATUS ADORA2B   ENTPD1
TCGA.HQ.A2OE.01                 38.57   0:LIVING 45.6397 643.4637
TCGA.FJ.A3Z9.01                 12.65 1:DECEASED 25.3327 982.4690
```

There were 2 empty strings in the case lists data of patient's tumor stage and they were indeed empty quotes ("").

```
> is.character(dat3$TUMOR_STAGE)
[1] TRUE
> is.na(dat3$TUMOR_STAGE)
[1] FALSE FALSE
> which(dat3$TUMOR_STAGE == "")
[1] 1 2
```

It's not difficult to remove them, I use filter()

```
#dat is the actual dataframe    
dat <- dat %>% filter(!TUMOR_STAGE == "")
```

But the question is, for a large downloaded dataframe, what if I don't know whether there is such "empty quotes"? Is there any R function that can be used to check this and remove the rows/columns containing such values?

Comment: Imho you are overthinking the problem. Just run the filter function you stated. If there are no such cases, then nothing will happen. If so, they will be deleted.

Comment: The only thing I recommend changing is to use `TUMOR_STAGE != ""` instead of the prefix negation you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do Something like:

```
if('' %in% dat$TUMOR_STAGE){dat_new = dat[!dat$TUMOR_STAGE%in%'',]}
```

And to apply it to all column, you can extend it with a `for` loop

Comment: The `if` is redundant, and `!x %in% y` for single-value `y` is more customarily written as `x != y`. What you’re then left with is identical to what OP already has (just using subsetting instead of the `filter` function).

Comment: Well, the `if` is just to check before doing the filtration. I sometime have bad surprise when filtering things if none of the rows are concerned by the filtering

Comment: Sorry, that doesn’t make sense: if there’s nothing to filter then the filter simply removes nothing: having the `if` literally has the same effect as removing it. It’s code that has no purpose.

Comment: FYI, the `nzchar` function tests for non-zero length character strings. So a combination of `nzchar` and `!is.na` can give you the indices to filter on, e.g. ` c("a", " ", "", NA) |> (\\(x) nzchar(x) & !is.na(x))()`